# Trajectory of a projectile: ODE form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, simulations, software

I need to model the Trajectory of a projectile in Matlab (with and without air resitance). Unfortunately I had my last physic lessons is years ago :).

I checked: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile

Is this even a second order problem?
Are my initial equations correct (alpha is the angle and v0 the inital velocity)?

```
 vx (=dx) has a start value of  v0*cos(alpha)
 vy (=dy) has a start value of v0*sin(alpha)
```

But how does the system of differential equations look like?
Is there a way to write it in a form of:

```
x'' = ...
Y'' = ...
```

and then convert it into an ODEform:

```
x' = ...
Y' = ...
```